# Is there a way to wait until a function is finished in React Native?

Tags: react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I'm trying to get information (true/false) from AsyncStorage in a function and create a string which is importent to fetch data in the next step. My problem is, the function is not finished until the string is required.

I tried many solutions from the internet like async function and await getItem or .done() or .then(), but none worked out for me.

```
//_getFetchData()
AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then((result) => { //get all stored Keys
  valuelength = result.length;
  if (valuelength !== 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < valuelength; i++) {
      if (result[i].includes("not") == false) { //get Keys without not
        AsyncStorage.getItem(result[i]).then((resultvalue) => {
          if (resultvalue === 'true') {
            if (this.state.firstValue) {
              this.state.channels = this.state.channels + "channel_id" + result[i];
              console.log("channel: " + this.state.channels);
            }
            else {
              this.state.channels = this.state.channels + "channel" + result[i];
            }
          }
        });
      }
return this.state.channels;

_fetchData() {
var channel = this._getFetchData();
console.log("channel required: " + channel);
}
```

The current behaviour is that the console displays first "channel required: " than "channel: channel_id0".

Comment: Reverted the question back to its original form as the change makes the original answers nonsensical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aspects in your question are unclear:

1. You don't say when `this.state.firstValue` is set, and how that relates to what you are trying to accomplish.
2. You have a `for-loop` where you could be setting the same value multiple times.
3. You **mutate** the state rather than set it. This is not good, see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really) for more on that.

There are somethings we can do to make your code easier to understand. Below I will show a possible refactor. Explaining what I am doing at each step. I am using `async/await` because it can lead to much tidier and easier to read code, rather than using `promises` where you can get lost in callbacks.

1. Get all the keys from AsyncStorage
2. Make sure that there is a value for all the keys.
3. Filter the keys so that we only include the ones that do not contain the string `'not'`.
4. Use a `Promise.all`, this part is important as it basically gets all the values for each of the keys that we just found and puts them into an array called `items`
5. Each object in the `items` array has a `key` and a `value` property.
6. We then filter the `items` so that only the ones with a `item.value === 'true'` remain.
7. We then filter the `items` so that only the ones with a `item.value !== 'true'` remain. (this may be optional it is really dependent on what you want to do)
8. What do we return? You need to add that part.

Here is the refactor:

```
_getFetchData = async () => {
  let allKeys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();                             // 1
  if (allKeys.length) {                                                      // 2

    let filteredKeys = allKeys.filter(key => !key.includes('not'));          // 3
    let items = await Promise.all(filteredKeys.map(async key => {            // 4
      let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
      return { key, value };                                                 // 5
    }))

    let filteredTrueItems = items.filter(item => items.value === 'true');    // 6
    let filteredFalseItems = items.filter(item => items.value !== 'true');   // 7
    // now you have two arrays one with the items that have the true values 
    // and one with the items that have the false values
    // at this points you can decide what to return as it is not 
    // that clear from your question

    // return the value that your want                                       // 8
  } else {
    // return your default value if there are no keys                        // 8
  }
}
```

You would call this function as follows:

```
_fetchData = async () => {
  let channel = await this._getFetchData();
  console.log("channel required: " + channel);
}
```

Although the above will work, it will not currently return a value as you haven't made it clear which value you wish to return. I would suggest you build upon the code that I have written here and update it so that it returns the values that you want.

## Further reading

For further reading I would suggest these awesome articles by Michael Chan that discuss `state`

https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-is-asynchronous-52ead919a3f0

https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296

https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-function-56eb940f84b6

I would also suggest taking some time to read up about `async/await` and `promises`

https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8

And finally this article and SO question on `Promise.all` are quite good

https://www.taniarascia.com/promise-all-with-async-await/

[Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

what if you wrap the `_getFetchData()` in a Promise? This would enable you to use

```
var channel = this._getFetchData().then(console.log("channel required: " + channel));
```

Otherwise the console.log won't wait for the execution of the _getFetchData().
This is what the console.log is telling you. it just logs the string. the variable is added after the async operation is done.

**UPDATE**

I would try this:

```
//_getFetchData()
AsyncStorage.getAllKeys().then((result) => { //get all stored Keys
  valuelength = result.length;
  if (valuelength !== 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < valuelength; i++) {
      if (result[i].includes("not") == false) { //get Keys without not
        AsyncStorage.getItem(result[i]).then((resultvalue) => {
          if (resultvalue === 'true') {
            if (this.state.firstValue) {
              this.state.channels = this.state.channels + "channel_id" + result[i];
              console.log("channel: " + this.state.channels);
            }
            else {
              this.state.channels = this.state.channels + "channel" + result[i];
            }
          }
        });
      }
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.state.channels !=== undefined ? resolve(this.state.channels) : reject(Error('error '));
}

_fetchData() {
var channel = this._getFetchData().then(console.log("channel required: " + channel));
}
```

maybe you must change the `this.state.channels !=== undefined` to an expression that's matches the default value of `this.state.channels`.

Comment: Now I get "channel required: undefined", but I need to say I'm not quite sure if I implemented the Promise right because I'm new to React Native.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. Async functions and Promises can be tricky to get right and can be difficult to debug but you're on the right track.

```
async _getFetchData() {
    let channels = "";

    let results = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();

    results.forEach((result) => {
        if (result.includes("not") === false) {
            let item = await AsyncStorage.getItem(result);

            if (item === 'true') {
                console.log(`channel: ${result}`)

                channels = `channel_id ${result}`;
            }
        }
    });

    return channels;
}

_fetchData() {
    this._getFetchData().then((channels) => {
        console.log(`channel required: ${channel}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but I get "await is a reserved word" at "let item = await AsyncStorage.getItem(result);". At getAllKeys() it works fine.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to add `async` in front of the arrow function for the `forEach()` function as well. So line 6 should be `results.forEach(async (result) => {`